# Optional type '$T11' cannot be used as a boolean; test for '!= nil' instead since installing XCode 6 beta 7

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, xcode6-beta7

**Here is the code where I'm getting the error:**

```
for (key, value) in info {
    let fieldValue: AnyObject? = value

    if (!fieldValue || fieldValue?.length == 0) { // this line gives the error
        informationComplete = false;
    } 
}
```

**This is what XCode suggests I use which causes another error:**

```
for (key, value) in info {
    let fieldValue: AnyObject? = value

    if ((!fieldValue || fieldValue?.length == 0) != nil) { //bool not convertible to string
        informationComplete = false;
    }
 }
```

Help is appreciated.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Optionals are no longer considered boolean expression (as stated in the Swift Reference - [Revision History](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/RevisionHistory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH40-XID_1636)):

> Optionals no longer implicitly evaluate to true when they have a value and false when they do not, to avoid confusion when working with optional Bool values. Instead, make an explicit check against nil with the == or != operators to find out if an optional contains a value.

so you have to make it explicit as follows:

```
if (fieldValue == nil || ...
```

I remember that changed in beta 6 - were you using beta 5?

Comment: Thanks. I bookmarked that revision list. I was using XCode beta 3 or 4 previously I think.